# What does "except" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can anybody explain the sentence in bold for me, please?

> "**If the Chinese were doing anything except what they're doing** I think the Western manufacturers would be terrified," said Aboulafia. "They are taking a convoluted and at times a counterproductive approach to developing this industry."

<sup>(Source: [CNBC: China's push into the passenger jet market is not seen as an immediate threat to Boeing, Airbus](http://www.cnbc.com/2017/05/08/chinas-new-passenger-jet-is-not-seen-as-an-immediate-threat-to-boeing-airbus.html))</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break the sentence

> **If the Chinese were doing anything** except **what they're doing**

into two parts.

The latter part, "**what they're doing**" refers to their convoluted and counterproductive approach at building a commercial plane.

"**If the Chinese were doing anything except**" means that were they building a plane with a different (uncomplicated and productive) approach, it would give the western manufacturers -- Boeing and Airbus, as mentioned in the actual article -- reason to be terrified for the loss of sales.

The reason that the writer thinks that their approach is convoluted and at times unproductive is listed here -

> First, he believes the heavy hand of a state-owned enterprise is the wrong approach to cracking into the global commercial aircraft business. Second, he maintains that partnering with Western equipment manufacturers under preconditions such as a requirement of Chinese manufacturing will add risk and ultimately not bring the most current technology, due to intellectual property concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Except, in this context, means "other than" which would have been the better way to phrase it in the first place.